# Magento - Show custom data on Order Information page (Customer Account)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to display points earned by customer on Order Information page under customer account.

**module.xml**

```
<sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_items">
            <action method="addItemRender" ifconfig="mymodule/general/active"><type>default</type>
                <block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block>
                <template>namespace/mymodule/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
</sales_order_view>
```

Copied file from core - `sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` to `namespace/mymodule/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` and along with default code, I added mine

```
<!--show points earned on each product-->
    <?php $finalPointsEarned = ($_item->getCustomerProductPoints() * $_item->getQtyOrdered()); ?>
    <div class="product-cart-sku">
        <span style="color: #d4af37; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $this->__('Points Earned:'); ?>
            <?php echo $finalPointsEarned ?>
        </span>
    </div>
<!--show points earned on each product-->
```

As shown in below image, this is how points earned are shown

[image]

1. Is this the correct approach/method to show custom data on Order
   Information page ?
2. If not, how do I override `Sales/Order/Item/Rendered/Default` block to show the same without copying core file
   in my extension and then adding my code ?

Will it be same for below mentioned files too ?

```
sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/
sales/order/shipment/items/renderer/
sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/
```

Also, I am showing the same information in admin section by copying files in my extension

```
adminhtml\default\default\template\namespace\modulename\sales\order\total.phtml
```

P.S. The files belongs to community extension

Answer (score 0):

I think you follow standard way.

In order to override template file there are following way.

1. Copy core template in your theme template file and then customize
2. Create an extension and then override core template file in your extension

Second one is better when you either create an extension or theme for 3party users too.

First one is better when you have only your own store concern. is it up to you which one you would like to choose.

Thanks